# How to check notifications API using jQuery feature detection

Tags: jquery, html, notifications

Is there way to detect feature: "Notifications API" using jQuery 1.9+ ?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=notifications, http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/notifications/quick/, https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/128

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery attempts to shy away from all browser detection. From [this blog post](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/06/22/jquery-1-8-beta-1-see-whats-coming-and-going/):

> $.browser: Ever since jQuery 1.4, we’ve been evangelizing that browser detection via the user agent string is a bad idea. Yet we’ve been an enabler of bad practice by continuing to offer $.browser. As of jQuery 1.9 we’ll remove it entirely and you’ll need to use the 1.9 compat plugin. If your code isn’t weaned off browser detection yet, check out Modernizr for a very thorough set of feature detections you can use instead. And of course, you’re welcome to read the tea leaves in the navigator.userAgent string directly, there’s nothing stopping you but your conscience.

In your case, jQuery isn't required to do the detection:

```
if (window.Notification) {
    // notifications are possible
}
```

But from that point you need to handle asking for permission as well. There are a few walkthrough's if you search the internet on how to follow the flow for getting permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect if the browser supports it by using:

```
if (window.Notification) { ... }
```

Further information about Web Notifications can be found here: http://www.w3.org/TR/notifications/